# Rails Request Content-Type Seems incorrect when accessing API with AngularJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, doorkeeper

I have a straightforward Rails 4.1.4 application and I'm trying to connect an AngularJS application on a separate host to it's API. Whilst I'm have no problem accessing it, Rails seems to think the request is HTML and ignores the Content-Type: 'application/json'

```
Started GET "/api/v1/locations?access_token=xxx&headers=%7B%22Content-type%22:%22application%2Fjson%22%7D" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-03 17:12:11 +0100
Processing by Api::V1::LocationsController#index as HTML
Parameters: {"access_token"=>"xxx", "headers"=>"{\"Content-type\":\"application/json\"}"}
```

And in my NG application, I've tried a number of combinations of headers including:

```
app.factory('Location', ['$resource', "$localStorage",
  function($resource, $localStorage){
    return $resource('http://my-api.com/api/v1/locations/', {headers:{'Content-type' : 'application/json'}}, {
      query: {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'},
        isArray: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        params: { access_token: $localStorage.accessToken }
      }...
```

The response looks ok on the NG side, it's responding with JSON despite only having this in my locations controller:

```
class Api::V1::LocationsController < Api::V1::BaseController

  doorkeeper_for :all
  before_filter :authorize
  respond_to :json

  def index
   @locations = @current_user.locations.order("created_at desc").limit(5)
   respond_with @locations
  end

end
```

I have also set (and tested unset) the cors headers.

I read somewhere that Rails won't read the content-type header if there's forward slashes in it...

Whilst this doesn't appear to be causing many issues, I do think it's interfering with Doorkeeper that's part of the application.

Comment: Sorry for being off topic, but how did you handle the authentication with the api?

Comment: We use passport / express / node to authenticate securely and then pass the access token to Angular.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This wasn't a Rails problem. Turns out I needed to fiddle with some headers etc. in the NG config.

I added the following to app.js

```
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
// $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Accept"] = "application/json";
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
```

The second line threw an error but I've left in there for good measure.

Comment: Just wasted an hour trying to figure this out. I appreciate you posting this! Btw, this also fixes Restangular with rails as the back-end.